# Python NTLM login

Tags: python, urllib2, ntlm

I am trying to pull information from a url that requires NTLM login.

I originaly received 401 error and after some tweaks have been able to pull the page stating that I have input invalid credentials.

The username and password are correct yet I cannot get past the invalid credentials page.

**Lgn2.py**:

```
import urllib2
import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

login = open('c:/temp/login.txt')
open = login.read()
to = open.split()
user = str(to[0])
password = str(to[1])

url = "http://INSERT URL HERE.com/"
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)


opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)


response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print(response.read())
```

I have a username including a \ using the method above I do not get a double backslash in the name when it prints. Should I keep it to where print will have the double backslash in the name as apposed to exactly as the txt file has the username spelled?

The txt file is just a txt document with only:  **domain\user\name password**.

The second backslash in the middle of username would be part of the username.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/ has a username that looks like 'DOMAIN\User'. Does your username have a domain in it?

Comment: yes without the domain it will return a 401

Comment: What kind of auth mechanism is your web site using? If it's not set to  allow basic auth, then you have to use a digest - see the extended example on http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you didn't use a [raw string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> Unless an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, escape sequences in strings
>   are interpreted according to rules similar to those used by Standard
>   C.

```
>>> 'domain\user'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 6-7: truncated \uXXXX escape
>>> r'domain\user'
'domain\\user'
```

This works for me (in Python 2, not 3):

```
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
import urllib2

user = r'domain\user'
password = "passphrase"
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, "http://projects/", user, password)
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

url = "http://projects/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List=etc"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
headers = response.info()
print("headers: {}".format(headers))
body = response.read()
print("response: " + body)
```

Comment: Your Post is very helpful, I also wanted to add authentication header in ntlm that variable name is Userauth, please help me

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 8):

Our company has a proxy and uses NTLM.  To connect without having to place credentials in script I used:

```
import win32com.client

url = 'https://...'

h = win32com.client.Dispatch('WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1')
h.SetAutoLogonPolicy(0)
h.Open('GET', url, False)
h.Send()
result = h.responseText
result
```

Comment: Where do you use winreg in this?

Comment: I may have used winreg for something else in my code. I can't remember.  I don't think it is required for the above to work.  Let me know how you get on with it.

Comment: Well, it successfully opened pages... But then it turns out that we need to run our program on Linux and I haven't checked this since.